# How display summernote text in codeigniter view page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

How can I show a description?

```xml
<?php if ($course->description != null) {?>
    <div class="description-box view-more-parent">
        <div class="view-more" onclick="viewMore(this,'show')">+ View More</div>
        <div class="description-title">Description</div>
        <div class="description-content-wrap">
            <div class="description-content">
                <?php echo $course->description; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: That's a bit vague isn't it?  What's wrong with your code?  What is erroring out?

Comment: <?php echo $course->description; ?> this is good code to display description. The problem is in the string. Try var_dump ($course->description); and show what it showed

Comment: Solved ....
I used  <?php eho html_entity_decode($$course->description) ?>